# Windows Explorer cannot load the desktop, and will only open a File Explorer window

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, bsod

Yesterday, after a blue screen (memory dump), my Windows 7 has the following problem: it start, but it don't load explorer.exe, it only show a File Explorer windows (with regular hard disk etc).

I've tried to run explorer.exe (CTRL+ALT+CANC and run "explorer.exe") but it won't! It shows only file explorer windows: no desktop, no bottom bar, no windows ...

What can be happen ? 
How can i fix it ?

Comment: "it won't" What, *exactly,* happens when you try?

Comment: I run explorer.exe but it show only file explorer: no desktop, no bottom bar, no windows ... the only window is file explorer ... !

Comment: Please respond to requests for additional information by [edit]ing the original post next time. I've done it for you now; feel free to edit further.

Answer (score 0):

So here are a couple of ideas:

Boot in Safe Mode:

1. restart your computer
2. bang on F8 immediately after it starts up until it asks you if you want to boot in safe mode
3. Do that and hope that it works

If it works in safe mode, that means you installed some kind of software or have some kind of service that is making Windows really sad. So you're going to want to do a system restore as other people have suggested or try to uninstall software you've recently installed.

However, and this is going to sound silly, but this sounds like what happens when you have a second monitor plugged in somewhere and the one you're looking at is the second monitor. It doesn't get any of your desktop icons or a taskbar in Windows 7. Is that possible? Do you have a TV hooked up to your computer?

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact issue in my Windows 10 virtual machine.
I did this in WinRE, but as you have access to the Task Manager or another command interpreter via C.A.D. you can do it straight from normal mode (Or you can manually navigate to `C:\Windows\regedit.exe`).
Via `regedit` check in the system registry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon
```

in the `Shell` value.
If you want the full Windows shell, you MUST write `C:\Windows\explorer.exe` (Replace the path with the one the system is actually installed in your machine). In my case it was written just `explorer`, and that isn't enough to load the shell.